# Need example of std::unordered_map constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, unordered-map

Suppose I am using my own class as the key for `std::unordered_map`

```
class MyClass {
public:
    int a, b;
}
```

[www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/unordered_map/) lists the following constructor that can be used:

```
explicit unordered_map ( size_type n,
                         const hasher& hf = hasher(),
                         const key_equal& eql = key_equal(),
                         const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type() );
```

Can you give an example of how I can use the above constructor with all the parameters populated for constructing my `std::unordered_map<MyClass, std::string>`?

Comment: [This example here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/unordered_map) should give you a good idea of what is required.

Comment: @juanchopanza I understand hash and key_equal functors can be specified as part of the template. But can they be passed directly to the constructor without specifying them in the template? If so, how?

Comment: You just pass instances of the functors to the constructor. The particular position depends which constructor you are calling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [three std::unordered_map constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/unordered_map) that take instances of the hash and equality functors as parameters. This example shows how to use one of them:

```
struct MyHash {
  std::size_t operator()(const MyClass& k) const { .... }
};

struct MyEqual {
  bool operator()(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) const { .... }
};

std::unordered_map<MyClass, std::string, MyHash, MyEqual> m(42, // bucket count 
                                                            MyHash(), 
                                                            MyEqual());
```

Comment: Getting the following compile error: `‘bool MyEqual::operator==(const MyClass&, const MyClass&)’ must take exactly one argument` using gcc 4.7.2

Comment: @VictorLyuboslavsky OK, I found the error in my code. I had a stupid mistake in the `MyEqual` class. Now it should compile.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a class that is able to be used as a key inside `unordered_map` isn't for free, they  need a custom hash object for this.

```
struct MyHash {
  std::size_t operator()(const MyClass& k) const
  {
    // You may want to use a better hash function
    return static_cast<std::size_t>(k.a) ^ static_cast<std::size_t>(k.b);
  }
};
```

Then, pass the hash function to the map as a template parameter (which constructs the hash object with the default constructor, so you don't need to pass it manually):

```
std::unordered_map<MyClass, std::string, MyHash> m;
```

Alternatively, you can provide the hash function inside the `std` namespace.

```
namespace std {
  template <>
  struct hash<MyClass> {
    std::size_t operator()(const MyClass& k) const; // same as before
  };
}
```

Now, it's exactly as expected:

```
std::unordered_map<MyClass, std::string> m;
```

Beside the special requirements for `unordered_map`, you also need to define a `operator==`.
 Even if this can be customized through a template parameter too, I suggest just writing it as a global function.

Comment: It still needs the equality comparison functor, or `operator==(const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs)`.